# How can I customise site search settings to use a wildcard for a specific entityRef field?

Tags: api, entityref

Is it possible to override the site search settings with respect to the wildcard search, for a specific entityRef field?

We have the site search setting configured with wildcard search disabled. On a particular custom form I'm injecting an entityRef field using the API to filter by Individual and group. I'd like to override that site setting and allow this to use a wildcard search.

Answer (score 1):

Currently no, it cannot be overridden on a per-field basis. But I could add a core patch to do so if your organization can fund a couple hours work.